# Puzzle disguised as cryptic clues

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

Here are some cryptic clues which hide a different type of puzzle. What kind of puzzle is it? Can you solve it?

> 1. Apple product obscured by acid erosion (5)
> 2. Yalta attendee unwell after mission (9)
> 3. House pets are fantastic at sneaking in secret (4)
> 4. Metal container is able to dance (3-3)
> 5. Bitter retiree's heart belongs to vehicle having audio equipment (7)
> 6. Group of beginners follow Latin girl to big city (7)
> 7. Spirit dance expels two head honchos (7)
> 8. Theatrical entertainment is bizarre bear act (7)
> 9. Court pulls out to back cigarette brand (5)
> 10. Communist leader with a mostly strong following (6)
> 11. African predator is reportedly unfair competitor (7)
> 12. Sun god carried by stylish Frenchman (6)
> 13. In the common era, a top Japanese skinned a dog relative (6)
> 14. Dictator leading central African republic around backwater sea (6)
> 15. Gear wheel not available with carbon solution (6)
> 16. Older woman in the distance removes top after incomplete hack (6)

Comment: is it a connect wall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solutions to the cryptic clues are:

1. > CIDER - a)CID ER(osion = "Apple product"
2. > CHURCHILL - CHURCH + ILL = Yalta attendee
3. > CATS - fantasti)C AT S(neaking = House pets
4. > CAN-CAN - CAN + CAN = dance
5. > CAMPARI - AMP in CAR + I = bitter
6. > CHICAGO - CHICA + G(roup) O(f) = big city
7. > CACHACA - C(h)A CHA C(h)A = Spirit
8. > CABARET - (BEAR ACT)* = Theatrical entertainment
9. > CAMEL - CAMEL(ot = OT<) = cigarette brand
10. > CASTRO - C(ommunist) + A + STRO(ng) = &lit.
11. > CHEETAH - homophone of cheater = African predator
12. > CHIRAC - CHI(RA)C = Frenchman
13. > COYOTE - (t)OYOT(a) in CE = dog relative
14. > CAESAR - SEA< in CAR = dictator
15. > COGNAC - C in COG + N/A = solution
16. > COUGAR - COUG(h) + (f)AR = older woman

The connection, ...

> ... as Jon Mark Perry astutely, er, pointed out in the comments, is a connect wall of:
>
>  **Cider**, **Cachaca**, **Campari**, **Cognac** – alcoholic drinks that begin with C
>  **Churchill**, **Castro**, **Chirac**, **Caesar** – state leaders that begin with C
>  **Camel**, **Cheetah**, **Coyote**, **Cougar** – quadrupeds that begin with C
>  **Can-Can**, **Chicago**, **Cabaret**, **Cats** – musicals that begin with C

Comment: Sniped!  I think your (h) should be an (e) in 16.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I'm reading it as a typo for (rot13 "PBHT(u)")

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: I'll leave the next one for you, @ChrisCudmore. Tommy is right: 16 has a typo.